# How do I add a new java mail version to my Apache Netbeans 11 project

Tags: java, email, netbeans, version

My project reports Java mail version 1.4.3. I have downloaded javax.mail-1.6.2.jar. I have found instructions for installing it and adding it to my project but they are badly outdated. Where can I find current step-by-step instructions?

Comment: Any modern Java project should be using Maven or Gradle to manage its libraries.

Comment: In the New Project wizard, choose Java with Maven and select Java Application.

Comment: Bear in mind that the `javax.mail` package has been migrated to [`jakarta.mail`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.0.1) for more recent versions. Background [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee).